# garbage collect javascript in popup when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, garbage-collection

**The case:**

Ok, so I have a popup which load a view from the server via ajax, this view could have JavaScript sometimes, and I assign this view to the popup by using jquery `.html(page)`

**The problem**

The popup JavaScript functions & variables are still alive even after I load a new view into the popup (which clear the old popup content because i'm using `html()`).

**Possible solution**

If I use iframe into the popup, I think the JavaScript ganna be cleared cause it simulate page refresh, but is there any other way ?, and am i right about iframe ?

**The code:**

Nothing special, just an ajax function which load a view:

```js
function ajaxLoad(url1, async, method1, data1, placeOrCallback, loader = false, loadFromParent = false) {
  var placeContent = null;

  $.ajax({
    url: url1,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    async: async,
    cache: false,
    method: method1,
    data: data1,
    beforeSend: function() {
      if (loader) {
        placeContent = $(placeOrCallback).html();
        $(placeOrCallback).html(spinnerLoader);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + " " + url1);
      console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
      for (key in xhr.responseJSON.errors) {
        snackbar(xhr.responseJSON.errors[key]);
      }
      if (loader === true) {
        $(placeOrCallback).html(placeContent);
      }

    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (typeof placeOrCallback === 'function') {
        placeOrCallback(result);
      } else {
        if (loadFromParent === false)
          $(placeOrCallback).html(result);
        else
          $(placeOrCallback, window.parent.document).html(result);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And an example of the returned view:

```
<script>
    let variables = "something";
    function finishTrain(e) {
        e.parent().remove();
        let amountDom = $("#armyTrain .card[data-type=infantry] .grid .amount");
        let currentAvailable = amountDom.html();
        amountDom.html(Number(currentAvailable) + 1);

    }

    $("#armyTrain .card:not(.locked) > img").on('click', function (e) {
        let armyInProgress = $("#armyInProgress");
        let type = $(this).parent().attr('data-type');
        let trainTime = $(this).parent().attr('data-trainTime');
        // let trainTime = 5;
        ajaxUpload('{{route('train')}}', true, {'unit': type});
        let card = '<div class="col-1">\n' +
            '            <div class="card">\n' +
            '\n' +
            '                <img src="/images/close.svg" alt="close" class="close-btn w-xm">\n' +
            '                <img src="/images/' + type + '.svg" alt="' + type + '">\n' +
            '\n' +
            '                <div class="in-progress" style="width: 50%;">\n' +
            '\n' +
            '                </div>\n' +
            '            </div>\n' +
            '        </div>';


        armyInProgress.append(card);

        runInProgress(armyInProgress.find(".card").last(), trainTime,0,finishTrain)
    })


    </script>
some html tags ..
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot really help you diagnose and fix any issues. However, you should note that in terms of garbage collections, events handlers are unattached when an element is removed from the DOM, no matter *how* it's removed. If your events are being retained after the content changes, then I would suspect you're using delegated event handlers, where the target parent element is not being removed from the DOM and hence events on the the new children are bubbling up and being caught.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry i just notice that functions and variables is still alive, anyway to delete them ?, and i attached the code

Comment: Thanks for adding the AJAX logic to the question, however we also need to see the event handlers which are being retained

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok added, some functions are already global for all popup, like `runInProgress`